# referenceData method called twice

Tags: spring-mvc, timeout

I am new to spring mvc.I am using simpleformcontroller.Everything is working fine.
But when users timeouts and try to login again the referenceData method is called twice.
It is very simple application.There is no error in the  code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to my own question.I used request setattribute method in spring controller.First time it sets the attribute and if second invocation happens it avoids unnecessary code execution.However it doesn't stops the second call but it is good to reduce bad effect of second call.

Hth
Jagdev